# Compare two images with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, compare

I am trying to take two images and compare them using ImageMagick.

I want to find out if the images are close to the same and return a number to be stored in a variable in php and displayed in my browser screen.

My hosting account is with bluehost and I have tested by resizing an image and ImageMagick is installed and running. The following code works here: http://zing-cards.com/imagetest2.php

```
<?php
$photo="/home/tcsdesig/public_html/zing/flower.jpg";
$cmd = "/usr/bin/convert $photo -thumbnail 100x100 JPG:-";

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
passthru($cmd, $retval);

?>
```

I understand the the following command line code (according to this [post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15767)) is supposed to get the results in a number format:

```
compare -metric RMSE first.png second.png NULL:
```

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$photoPath1="/home/*username*/public_html/flower.jpg";
$photoPath2="/home/*username*/public_html/flower1.jpg";

$cmd = "/usr/bin/compare -metric RMSE $photoPath1 $photoPath2 NULL:";
exec($cmd);
?>
```

How do I make this value show in my browser?

Other than the above code I have tried:

```
$result = exec($cmd);
echo $result;
```

From what I understand this should display a low number (since the images are equal) and if I use completely different images they should display a high number but I don't get any results.

Answer (score 2):

Here if I do

```
<?php
    $photoPath1="/home/*username*/public_html/flower.jpg";
    $photoPath2="/home/*username*/public_html/flower1.jpg";

    $result = exec("/usr/bin/compare -metric RMSE /usr/share/pixmaps/faces/dice.jpg /usr/share/pixmaps/faces/fish.jpg NULL:");
    echo $result;
?>
```

I get

```
20455.4 (0.312129)
```

Which is what I expect, because the images are completely different...

I suppose you should try `compare` on the command-line, beforehand...

For example, if you don't have `compare` installed on your system, you don't get any results...

**UPDATE**: To further investigate in case of persistent lack of output, please do:

```
<?php
    $photoPath1 = "/home/*username*/public_html/flower.jpg";
    $photoPath2 = "/home/*username*/public_html/flower1.jpg";

    $compareCommand = "/usr/bin/compare";
    if (!is_executable($compareCommand)) die("Sorry, can't execute $compareCommand!");
    $output = shell_exec("$compareCommand -metric RMSE $photoPath1 $photoPath2 NULL: 2>&1");
    print $output;
?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Answering OP question in comment:

In the convert man page it's not specified if and how it's possible to print only the RMSE error percentage...

You could add (for example) a `| sed -e 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/g'` to the command, to just keep RMSE error percentage...

Comment: I simplified my code: 

It is here: http://zing-cards.com/imagecompare.php



<?php
echo "<h1>Compare Images</h1>";

$result = exec("/usr/bin/compare -metric RMSE  /home/*username*/public_html/zing/flower.jpg /home/*username*/public_html/zing/woman1.png NULL:");
echo "Result:" . $result;
?>

Comment: Are you using Bluehost? Is there anything I have to do to install or activate compare? As I said the convert command works. I just get a blank, no result. Is there a way to make imagemagick output an error code?

Comment: I don't have imagick installed: http://zing-cards.com/imagick.php could that be a problem? This page is coded like this: <?php
if (!extension_loaded('imagick'))
    echo 'imagick not installed';
?>

Comment: Bluehost says that I am getting my data before I load my content type. How do I get around this?

Comment: header("Content-type: text/html");
$result = exec("/usr/bin/compare -metric RMSE  /home/tcsdesig/public_html/zing/flower.jpg /home/tcsdesig/public_html/zing/woman1.png NULL:");
echo $result;

Comment: I just now got back to this project and your solution works. Now the question I have is that if I get back a number like "11422 (0.174288)" is there any part of the command line that I can use to just return "0.174288"? I know I can do this through php by breaking up the number returned by splitting it at the space and removing the parenthesis but I would rather just get the number out of the compare command.