# best way to compare two images in either PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, web-scraping, image-comparison

I need to know In which language I will get best image compare script. There is some point:

1. compare images color and background color.
2. compare objects in images. Like first image have 1 bottle but second image have 2 bottles then script will let us know the object differences.
3. Size of images.

I have depth knowledge of Python and PHP. Kindly help me out.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533323/compare-two-images-with-imagemagick or make sure you have `imagemagick` installed and check out http://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

Comment: I need to count the objects on the image through opencv library in python. How to proceed?